# Cant reply json on discord.py

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

Im making a cripto price tracker and i cant make it reply the json that im making with the coin decko URL and Arg1 for example Eternal or SLP, etc.

```
# bot = scrt.bot
bot   = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")
login = 0



tokens_dict = {
    'morw' :     '0x6b61b24504a6378e1a99d2aa2a5efcb1f5627a3a',
    'slp'  :     '0xcc8fa225d80b9c7d42f96e9570156c65d6caaa25',
    'pvu'  :     '0x31471e0791fcdbe82fbf4c44943255e923f1b794',
    'eternal' :  '0xd44fd09d74cd13838f137b590497595d6b3feea4'
}

# Login
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    global login
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))
    login = 1

@bot.command()
async def coin(ctx, arg1):
    global tokens_dict

    if(arg1 in tokens_dict.keys()):
        url = 'https://api.pancakeswap.info/api/v2/tokens/' + tokens_dict[arg1]
        response = request.get(url)
        responseDict = json.loads(response.text)
        await ctx.reply(responseDict)
    else:
        await ctx.reply("The token " + str(arg1) +  " is not in the token list, if you want to add " + str(arg1) + " to the list please use the command : " + '\n' + "!add_token")
```

In the coin function im trying to reply the json that ive created but i dont know how to.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     response = request.get(url)
>     responseDict = json.loads(response.text)
>     await ctx.reply(responseDict)
> ```

I'm assuming this is the part you're talking about.

You actually don't need to call `json.loads(response.text)` if you're going to send it anyway. If the raw response is unformatted then you can do this

```
response_dict = json.loads(response.text)
formatted_dict = json.dumps(response_dict, indent=4)
await ctx.reply(formatted_dict)
```

This should send the json as a string with indents.
The reason discord.py wasn't letting you send the message was because it wasn't a string.

Comment: It didn't work ):